# Unable to parse OpenJson if value dont have key name

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, parsing, json.net

I have some json that I would like to parse in SQL Server 2019.
There is a hierarchy structure of Conversations->Divisions.
I would like to write a query that parses the whole hierarchy

Divisons are coming as null

```
DECLARE @JsonContent NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @JsonContent  = '
{
  "conversations": [
    {
      "originatingDirection": "inbound",
      "conversationEnd": "2021-03-18T12:39:57.587Z",
      "conversationId": "46f7cda7-ad75-4a1e-b28c-b1c8c01e609e",
      "conversationStart": "2021-03-18T12:39:01.206Z",
      "divisionIds": [
        "aaabbbba-ertw-cldl-2021-547fff22ff33",
        "ddfrgfsc-c3e4-a8f9-b28c-b1c8c01e609e"
      ]
      }]
      }'

SELECT * FROM
OPENJSON(@JsonContent, '$.conversations')
WITH (
originatingDirection NVARCHAR(50) '$.originatingDirection',
conversationEnd NVARCHAR(50) '$.conversationEnd',
conversationId NVARCHAR(50) '$.conversationId',
conversationStart NVARCHAR(50) '$.conversationStart',
divisionIds NVARCHAR(50) '$.conversations.divisionIds'

)
```

[image: Results screenshot]

Comment: What is your question? You should use a sentence that can end with a question mark to clearly tell people what you're looking for.

Comment: Zhorov helped me out.
see the below response.

Answer (score 1):

You need a different path (`'$.divisionIds'`) and `AS JSON` to parse the `$.divisionIds` part of the input JSON and an additional `APPLY` operator to parse the nested JSON array:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@JsonContent, '$.conversations') WITH (
   originatingDirection NVARCHAR(50) '$.originatingDirection',
   conversationEnd NVARCHAR(50) '$.conversationEnd',
   conversationId NVARCHAR(50) '$.conversationId',
   conversationStart NVARCHAR(50) '$.conversationStart',
   divisionIds NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.divisionIds' AS JSON
) c
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (c.divisionIds) WITH (
   divisionId NVARCHAR(50) '$'
) d
```

Comment: @SuryaVanamoju, If you think that this or any other answer is the best solution to your problem, you may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. Only one answer can be accepted.